# Custom cursor dissapears as you scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web development and just started learning html, css and js. I used the code I found on [codepen](https://codepen.io/apexskier) here to make a custom cursor with a "trail"(there are in fact 2 cursors in my code (cursor and cursor2, where cursor uses svg so it is not visible).

The cursor works fine till the moment I start scrolling down, and I have absolutely no clue what causes it. Hours of googling did not help.

Sorry if the solution to this problem might be very obvious T__T

Please see my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/alinator_bambie/pen/YzXbRWd).
Thank you very much!!

```js
 const cursor= document.querySelector('.cursor');
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
     cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+ (e.pageY-60)+"px;left: "+(e.pageX-40)+ "px;")
    })


    var settings = {
      colorChangeSpeedFactor: .1, // how fast does the color changes? Lower is slower, exponential
      trailLength: 150, // how long is the trail?
      diameter: 30, // how wide is the spray mark?
      fadeStart: .8 // where does the trail start fading out? percentage along itself
    }
    var __meta_settings__ = {
      disabled: true
    }
    
    const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
    
    // just some dummy data to make a not blank initial page
    var cursorTrail = JSON.parse(`[{"hue":311.454399995273,"speed":7.0710678118654755,"x":157,"y":131},{"hue":313.1217999965884,"speed":4.242640687119285,"x":160,"y":128},{"hue":314.7891999979038,"speed":7.211102550927978,"x":164,"y":122},{"hue":316.4565999992192,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":166,"y":117},{"hue":318.1240000005346,"speed":14.035668847618199,"x":167,"y":103},{"hue":319.7913999960292,"speed":10.04987562112089,"x":166,"y":93},{"hue":321.4587999973446,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":163,"y":85},{"hue":323.12619999866,"speed":0,"x":163,"y":85},{"hue":324.7935999999754,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":161,"y":76},{"hue":326.46099999547005,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":160,"y":70},{"hue":328.12839999678545,"speed":3.1622776601683795,"x":159,"y":67},{"hue":329.79579999810085,"speed":3,"x":159,"y":64},{"hue":331.46319999941625,"speed":2,"x":159,"y":62},{"hue":334.7979999962263,"speed":2.8284271247461903,"x":161,"y":60},{"hue":336.4653999975417,"speed":4.123105625617661,"x":165,"y":59},{"hue":338.1327999988571,"speed":6,"x":171,"y":59},{"hue":339.8002000001725,"speed":5,"x":176,"y":59},{"hue":341.4675999956671,"speed":9,"x":185,"y":59},{"hue":343.1349999969825,"speed":8.06225774829855,"x":193,"y":60},{"hue":344.8023999982979,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":201,"y":63},{"hue":346.4697999996133,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":208,"y":65},{"hue":348.13719999510795,"speed":6.708203932499369,"x":214,"y":68},{"hue":349.80459999642335,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":219,"y":69},{"hue":351.47199999773875,"speed":3.1622776601683795,"x":222,"y":70},{"hue":353.13939999905415,"speed":3,"x":225,"y":70},{"hue":354.80680000036955,"speed":2,"x":227,"y":70},{"hue":356.4741999958642,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":232,"y":68},{"hue":358.1415999971796,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":234,"y":65},{"hue":359.808999998495,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":235,"y":59},{"hue":1.4763999998103827,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":236,"y":54},{"hue":3.1437999953050166,"speed":4,"x":236,"y":50},{"hue":4.811199996620417,"speed":5,"x":236,"y":45},{"hue":6.478599997935817,"speed":7.810249675906654,"x":231,"y":39},{"hue":8.145999999251217,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":224,"y":33},{"hue":9.813400000566617,"speed":11.180339887498949,"x":214,"y":28},{"hue":11.48079999606125,"speed":11.180339887498949,"x":204,"y":23},{"hue":13.14819999737665,"speed":12.649110640673518,"x":192,"y":19},{"hue":14.81559999869205,"speed":0,"x":192,"y":19},{"hue":16.48300000000745,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":185,"y":17},{"hue":18.150399995502084,"speed":10.198039027185569,"x":175,"y":15},{"hue":19.817799996817484,"speed":15.297058540778355,"x":160,"y":12},{"hue":21.485199998132885,"speed":0,"x":160,"y":12},{"hue":23.152599999448285,"speed":8.06225774829855,"x":152,"y":11},{"hue":24.81999999494292,"speed":5,"x":147,"y":11},{"hue":26.48739999625832,"speed":6,"x":141,"y":11},{"hue":28.15479999757372,"speed":7,"x":134,"y":11},{"hue":29.82219999888912,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":128,"y":12},{"hue":31.48960000020452,"speed":6.324555320336759,"x":122,"y":14},{"hue":33.15699999569915,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":115,"y":16},{"hue":34.82439999701455,"speed":10.295630140987,"x":106,"y":21},{"hue":36.49179999832995,"speed":5.830951894845301,"x":101,"y":24},{"hue":38.15919999964535,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":93,"y":27},{"hue":39.826599995139986,"speed":7.810249675906654,"x":87,"y":32},{"hue":41.493999996455386,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":80,"y":38},{"hue":43.161399997770786,"speed":5.656854249492381,"x":76,"y":42},{"hue":44.828799999086186,"speed":12.041594578792296,"x":67,"y":50},{"hue":46.496200000401586,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":65,"y":53},{"hue":48.16359999589622,"speed":0,"x":65,"y":53},{"hue":49.83099999721162,"speed":4.242640687119285,"x":62,"y":56},{"hue":51.49839999852702,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":60,"y":60},{"hue":53.16579999984242,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":59,"y":65},{"hue":54.833199995337054,"speed":6.324555320336759,"x":57,"y":71},{"hue":56.500599996652454,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":56,"y":77},{"hue":58.167999997967854,"speed":7,"x":56,"y":84},{"hue":59.835399999283254,"speed":4,"x":56,"y":88},{"hue":61.502800000598654,"speed":3,"x":56,"y":91},{"hue":63.17019999609329,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":61,"y":93},{"hue":64.83759999740869,"speed":9.486832980505138,"x":70,"y":96},{"hue":66.50499999872409,"speed":8,"x":78,"y":96},{"hue":68.17240000003949,"speed":13,"x":91,"y":96},{"hue":69.83979999553412,"speed":14,"x":105,"y":96},{"hue":71.50719999684952,"speed":11,"x":116,"y":96},{"hue":73.17459999816492,"speed":0,"x":116,"y":96},{"hue":74.84199999948032,"speed":10,"x":126,"y":96},{"hue":76.50939999497496,"speed":7,"x":133,"y":96},{"hue":78.17679999629036,"speed":7.0710678118654755,"x":140,"y":97},{"hue":79.84419999760576,"speed":2.23606797749979,"x":142,"y":98},{"hue":81.51159999892116,"speed":2.8284271247461903,"x":144,"y":100},{"hue":83.17900000023656,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":146,"y":103},{"hue":84.84639999573119,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":147,"y":108},{"hue":86.51379999704659,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":149,"y":115},{"hue":89.84859999967739,"speed":24.515301344262525,"x":144,"y":139},{"hue":91.51599999517202,"speed":15.231546211727817,"x":138,"y":153},{"hue":93.18339999648742,"speed":11.661903789690601,"x":132,"y":163},{"hue":94.85079999780282,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":129,"y":171},{"hue":96.51819999911822,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":127,"y":175},{"hue":98.18560000043362,"speed":2,"x":127,"y":177},{"hue":101.52039999724366,"speed":1,"x":127,"y":178},{"hue":103.18779999855906,"speed":1,"x":127,"y":179},{"hue":104.85519999987446,"speed":25.179356624028344,"x":152,"y":182},{"hue":106.52259999536909,"speed":23.194827009486403,"x":175,"y":185},{"hue":109.85739999799989,"speed":16.0312195418814,"x":191,"y":186},{"hue":113.19220000063069,"speed":24.331050121192877,"x":215,"y":190},{"hue":119.86180000007153,"speed":12.36931687685298,"x":227,"y":193},{"hue":123.19659999688156,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":231,"y":195},{"hue":126.53139999951236,"speed":1,"x":232,"y":195},{"hue":129.8661999963224,"speed":1,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":131.5335999976378,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":133.2009999989532,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":134.8684000002686,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195}]`);
    
    // keep track of where the cursor is
    var cursorPos = {
      x: -100, // start outside the screen
      y: -100
    };
    
    function getPos(event) {
      return {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
      }
    }
    // can't get the mouse position outside of events, so cache it in the cursorPos object
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      cursorPos = getPos(e);
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      cursorPos = getPos(e.changedTouches[0]); // no multitouch support (yet? )
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent touch scrolling
    });
    
    // "hide" the cursor by moving it off screen
    //function goAway(e) {
     // cursorPos.x = -10;
     // cursorPos.y = -10;
  //  }
  //  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', goAway);
    //document.addEventListener('touchend', goAway);
    
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(cursorTrail));
    });
    
    function frame(time) {
      var hue = (time * settings.colorChangeSpeedFactor) % 360;
      
      cursorTrail.push(Object.assign({
        hue: hue,
        speed: cursorTrail.length <= 1 ? 0 : ((pos, lastPos) => {
          // distance between points ~ speed. Might be nice to smooth this by averaging over the last few points
          return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastPos.x - pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(lastPos.y - pos.y, 2));
        })(cursorPos, cursorTrail[cursorTrail.length - 1])
      }, cursorPos));
      
      // keep popping off the first one
      // nice little following effect, plus your browser would probably die if everything was kept
      if (cursorTrail.length > settings.trailLength) {
        cursorTrail.shift();
      }
    
      // follow the mouse!
      cursor2.style.top = `${cursorPos.y}px`;
      cursor2.style.left = `${cursorPos.x}px`;
      
    
      // generate a trail of shadows
      cursor2.style.boxShadow = cursorTrail.map((pos, i) => {
        const offsetX = pos.x - cursorPos.x;
        const offsetY = pos.y - cursorPos.y;
        const age = (settings.trailLength - i) / settings.trailLength;
        const fadeOut = age < settings.fadeStart ? 0 : Math.pow(4 * (age - settings.fadeStart), 2); 
        const color = `hsla(${pos.hue}, 50%, 50%, ${1 - fadeOut})`;
        // return `${offsetX}px ${offsetY}px ${pos.speed + 1}px ${age * settings.diameter + settings.diameter}px ${color}`;
        return `${offsetX}px ${offsetY}px ${pos.speed + 1}px ${settings.diameter}px ${color}`;
      }).reverse().join(', ');
    
      window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    
    console.log('initialized');
```

```css
/* scroll */ 

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0)
        }
    }

    @keyframes scroll {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0)
        }
    }



body {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background: white;
margin:0;
padding:0;
cursor: none;
position: absolute;
/*display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: column;*/
}

main{
width:100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: column;
position: fixed;}

header{
    padding:0;
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-left:5em;
    margin-right:5em;
    max-height:6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.container{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:6em;
    width:6em;
    background-color:blue;
  
}


footer{
        
        bottom: 0;
        padding:0;
        margin-bottom:3em;
        margin-left:5em;
        margin-right:5em;
        max-height:6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
       
}


 img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

svg{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    stroke:black;
    fill:none;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}



.cursor {
        background-image: url('images/moonstick_1.svg');
        position:absolute;
        height:100px;
        width:60px;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 12;
        
      }



      .cursor2 {
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 11;
        height:2px;
        width:2px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: none;
        opacity: 0.3;
        
        top: -100px;
        left: -100px;
      }


      section{

        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
        z-index:-1;
       
    }
    
    .projects{
         
            max-width: 80%;
            min-height:600px;
            background-color:white;
            margin-top:1em;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;           
    }

.project_content{
        display: flex;
        
}


.project_description{ 
        max-width:30%;
        z-index:5;
      }

      h1{ 
        font-family:  'technique_sansregular'; 
        font-size:3em; 
      }

      p { 
        font-family:  'technique_sansregular'; 
        font-size:1em; 
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>portfolio</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="style_works.css">
  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
  
    <main>
        <header>
        <dev class="works container">
            </dev>
            
        <dev class="about container">
           </dev>
        </header>
    
        <footer>
        <div class="invisible container">
            
            <h3 class=rights> </h3></div>
        
        <div class="blog container">
                </div>
        
        <div class="contacts container">
            
        </div>
        </footer>


        <div class="cursor2"></div>
       
       <div class="cursor"></div>
    
    </main>
    <section>

        <div class="projects">
            <div class="project_content">
                <div class="graphic_content">
            
                </div>
                <div class="project_description">
                    <h1>TITLE TITLE</h1>
                    <p> text
                        </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
         
            </div>
           
    </section>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to handle `window.scrollY` but I am not sure where to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `e.clientY` instead of `e.pageY` so that it is relative to the viewport, rather than the document behind the viewport.

```js
const cursor= document.querySelector('.cursor');
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
     cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+ (e.clientY-60)+"px;left: "+(e.clientX-40)+ "px;")
    })


    var settings = {
      colorChangeSpeedFactor: .1, // how fast does the color changes? Lower is slower, exponential
      trailLength: 150, // how long is the trail?
      diameter: 30, // how wide is the spray mark?
      fadeStart: .8 // where does the trail start fading out? percentage along itself
    }
    var __meta_settings__ = {
      disabled: true
    }
    
    const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
    
    // just some dummy data to make a not blank initial page
    var cursorTrail = JSON.parse(`[{"hue":311.454399995273,"speed":7.0710678118654755,"x":157,"y":131},{"hue":313.1217999965884,"speed":4.242640687119285,"x":160,"y":128},{"hue":314.7891999979038,"speed":7.211102550927978,"x":164,"y":122},{"hue":316.4565999992192,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":166,"y":117},{"hue":318.1240000005346,"speed":14.035668847618199,"x":167,"y":103},{"hue":319.7913999960292,"speed":10.04987562112089,"x":166,"y":93},{"hue":321.4587999973446,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":163,"y":85},{"hue":323.12619999866,"speed":0,"x":163,"y":85},{"hue":324.7935999999754,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":161,"y":76},{"hue":326.46099999547005,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":160,"y":70},{"hue":328.12839999678545,"speed":3.1622776601683795,"x":159,"y":67},{"hue":329.79579999810085,"speed":3,"x":159,"y":64},{"hue":331.46319999941625,"speed":2,"x":159,"y":62},{"hue":334.7979999962263,"speed":2.8284271247461903,"x":161,"y":60},{"hue":336.4653999975417,"speed":4.123105625617661,"x":165,"y":59},{"hue":338.1327999988571,"speed":6,"x":171,"y":59},{"hue":339.8002000001725,"speed":5,"x":176,"y":59},{"hue":341.4675999956671,"speed":9,"x":185,"y":59},{"hue":343.1349999969825,"speed":8.06225774829855,"x":193,"y":60},{"hue":344.8023999982979,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":201,"y":63},{"hue":346.4697999996133,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":208,"y":65},{"hue":348.13719999510795,"speed":6.708203932499369,"x":214,"y":68},{"hue":349.80459999642335,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":219,"y":69},{"hue":351.47199999773875,"speed":3.1622776601683795,"x":222,"y":70},{"hue":353.13939999905415,"speed":3,"x":225,"y":70},{"hue":354.80680000036955,"speed":2,"x":227,"y":70},{"hue":356.4741999958642,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":232,"y":68},{"hue":358.1415999971796,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":234,"y":65},{"hue":359.808999998495,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":235,"y":59},{"hue":1.4763999998103827,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":236,"y":54},{"hue":3.1437999953050166,"speed":4,"x":236,"y":50},{"hue":4.811199996620417,"speed":5,"x":236,"y":45},{"hue":6.478599997935817,"speed":7.810249675906654,"x":231,"y":39},{"hue":8.145999999251217,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":224,"y":33},{"hue":9.813400000566617,"speed":11.180339887498949,"x":214,"y":28},{"hue":11.48079999606125,"speed":11.180339887498949,"x":204,"y":23},{"hue":13.14819999737665,"speed":12.649110640673518,"x":192,"y":19},{"hue":14.81559999869205,"speed":0,"x":192,"y":19},{"hue":16.48300000000745,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":185,"y":17},{"hue":18.150399995502084,"speed":10.198039027185569,"x":175,"y":15},{"hue":19.817799996817484,"speed":15.297058540778355,"x":160,"y":12},{"hue":21.485199998132885,"speed":0,"x":160,"y":12},{"hue":23.152599999448285,"speed":8.06225774829855,"x":152,"y":11},{"hue":24.81999999494292,"speed":5,"x":147,"y":11},{"hue":26.48739999625832,"speed":6,"x":141,"y":11},{"hue":28.15479999757372,"speed":7,"x":134,"y":11},{"hue":29.82219999888912,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":128,"y":12},{"hue":31.48960000020452,"speed":6.324555320336759,"x":122,"y":14},{"hue":33.15699999569915,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":115,"y":16},{"hue":34.82439999701455,"speed":10.295630140987,"x":106,"y":21},{"hue":36.49179999832995,"speed":5.830951894845301,"x":101,"y":24},{"hue":38.15919999964535,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":93,"y":27},{"hue":39.826599995139986,"speed":7.810249675906654,"x":87,"y":32},{"hue":41.493999996455386,"speed":9.219544457292887,"x":80,"y":38},{"hue":43.161399997770786,"speed":5.656854249492381,"x":76,"y":42},{"hue":44.828799999086186,"speed":12.041594578792296,"x":67,"y":50},{"hue":46.496200000401586,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":65,"y":53},{"hue":48.16359999589622,"speed":0,"x":65,"y":53},{"hue":49.83099999721162,"speed":4.242640687119285,"x":62,"y":56},{"hue":51.49839999852702,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":60,"y":60},{"hue":53.16579999984242,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":59,"y":65},{"hue":54.833199995337054,"speed":6.324555320336759,"x":57,"y":71},{"hue":56.500599996652454,"speed":6.082762530298219,"x":56,"y":77},{"hue":58.167999997967854,"speed":7,"x":56,"y":84},{"hue":59.835399999283254,"speed":4,"x":56,"y":88},{"hue":61.502800000598654,"speed":3,"x":56,"y":91},{"hue":63.17019999609329,"speed":5.385164807134504,"x":61,"y":93},{"hue":64.83759999740869,"speed":9.486832980505138,"x":70,"y":96},{"hue":66.50499999872409,"speed":8,"x":78,"y":96},{"hue":68.17240000003949,"speed":13,"x":91,"y":96},{"hue":69.83979999553412,"speed":14,"x":105,"y":96},{"hue":71.50719999684952,"speed":11,"x":116,"y":96},{"hue":73.17459999816492,"speed":0,"x":116,"y":96},{"hue":74.84199999948032,"speed":10,"x":126,"y":96},{"hue":76.50939999497496,"speed":7,"x":133,"y":96},{"hue":78.17679999629036,"speed":7.0710678118654755,"x":140,"y":97},{"hue":79.84419999760576,"speed":2.23606797749979,"x":142,"y":98},{"hue":81.51159999892116,"speed":2.8284271247461903,"x":144,"y":100},{"hue":83.17900000023656,"speed":3.605551275463989,"x":146,"y":103},{"hue":84.84639999573119,"speed":5.0990195135927845,"x":147,"y":108},{"hue":86.51379999704659,"speed":7.280109889280518,"x":149,"y":115},{"hue":89.84859999967739,"speed":24.515301344262525,"x":144,"y":139},{"hue":91.51599999517202,"speed":15.231546211727817,"x":138,"y":153},{"hue":93.18339999648742,"speed":11.661903789690601,"x":132,"y":163},{"hue":94.85079999780282,"speed":8.54400374531753,"x":129,"y":171},{"hue":96.51819999911822,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":127,"y":175},{"hue":98.18560000043362,"speed":2,"x":127,"y":177},{"hue":101.52039999724366,"speed":1,"x":127,"y":178},{"hue":103.18779999855906,"speed":1,"x":127,"y":179},{"hue":104.85519999987446,"speed":25.179356624028344,"x":152,"y":182},{"hue":106.52259999536909,"speed":23.194827009486403,"x":175,"y":185},{"hue":109.85739999799989,"speed":16.0312195418814,"x":191,"y":186},{"hue":113.19220000063069,"speed":24.331050121192877,"x":215,"y":190},{"hue":119.86180000007153,"speed":12.36931687685298,"x":227,"y":193},{"hue":123.19659999688156,"speed":4.47213595499958,"x":231,"y":195},{"hue":126.53139999951236,"speed":1,"x":232,"y":195},{"hue":129.8661999963224,"speed":1,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":131.5335999976378,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":133.2009999989532,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195},{"hue":134.8684000002686,"speed":0,"x":233,"y":195}]`);
    
    // keep track of where the cursor is
    var cursorPos = {
      x: -100, // start outside the screen
      y: -100
    };
    
    function getPos(event) {
      return {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      }
    }
    // can't get the mouse position outside of events, so cache it in the cursorPos object
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      cursorPos = getPos(e);
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      cursorPos = getPos(e.changedTouches[0]); // no multitouch support (yet? )
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent touch scrolling
    });
    
    // "hide" the cursor by moving it off screen
    //function goAway(e) {
     // cursorPos.x = -10;
     // cursorPos.y = -10;
  //  }
  //  document.addEventListener('mouseleave', goAway);
    //document.addEventListener('touchend', goAway);
    
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(cursorTrail));
    });
    
    function frame(time) {
      var hue = (time * settings.colorChangeSpeedFactor) % 360;
      
      cursorTrail.push(Object.assign({
        hue: hue,
        speed: cursorTrail.length <= 1 ? 0 : ((pos, lastPos) => {
          // distance between points ~ speed. Might be nice to smooth this by averaging over the last few points
          return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastPos.x - pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(lastPos.y - pos.y, 2));
        })(cursorPos, cursorTrail[cursorTrail.length - 1])
      }, cursorPos));
      
      // keep popping off the first one
      // nice little following effect, plus your browser would probably die if everything was kept
      if (cursorTrail.length > settings.trailLength) {
        cursorTrail.shift();
      }
    
      // follow the mouse!
      cursor2.style.top = `${cursorPos.y}px`;
      cursor2.style.left = `${cursorPos.x}px`;
      
    
      // generate a trail of shadows
      cursor2.style.boxShadow = cursorTrail.map((pos, i) => {
        const offsetX = pos.x - cursorPos.x;
        const offsetY = pos.y - cursorPos.y;
        const age = (settings.trailLength - i) / settings.trailLength;
        const fadeOut = age < settings.fadeStart ? 0 : Math.pow(4 * (age - settings.fadeStart), 2); 
        const color = `hsla(${pos.hue}, 50%, 50%, ${1 - fadeOut})`;
        // return `${offsetX}px ${offsetY}px ${pos.speed + 1}px ${age * settings.diameter + settings.diameter}px ${color}`;
        return `${offsetX}px ${offsetY}px ${pos.speed + 1}px ${settings.diameter}px ${color}`;
      }).reverse().join(', ');
    
      window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    
    console.log('initialized');
```

```css
/* scroll */ 

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0)
        }
    }

    @keyframes scroll {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0)
        }
    }



body {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background: white;
margin:0;
padding:0;
cursor: none;
position: absolute;
/*display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: column;*/
}

main{
width:100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: column;
position: fixed;}

header{
    padding:0;
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-left:5em;
    margin-right:5em;
    max-height:6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.container{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:6em;
    width:6em;
    background-color:blue;
  
}


footer{
        
        bottom: 0;
        padding:0;
        margin-bottom:3em;
        margin-left:5em;
        margin-right:5em;
        max-height:6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
       
}


 img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

svg{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    stroke:black;
    fill:none;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}



.cursor {
        background-image: url('images/moonstick_1.svg');
        position:absolute;
        height:100px;
        width:60px;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 12;
        
      }



      .cursor2 {
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 11;
        height:2px;
        width:2px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: none;
        opacity: 0.3;
        
        top: -100px;
        left: -100px;
      }


      section{

        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
        z-index:-1;
       
    }
    
    .projects{
         
            max-width: 80%;
            min-height:600px;
            background-color:white;
            margin-top:1em;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;           
    }

.project_content{
        display: flex;
        
}


.project_description{ 
        max-width:30%;
        z-index:5;
      }

      h1{ 
        font-family:  'technique_sansregular'; 
        font-size:3em; 
      }

      p { 
        font-family:  'technique_sansregular'; 
        font-size:1em; 
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>portfolio</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="style_works.css">
  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
  
    <main>
        <header>
        <dev class="works container">
            </dev>
            
        <dev class="about container">
           </dev>
        </header>
    
        <footer>
        <div class="invisible container">
            
            <h3 class=rights> </h3></div>
        
        <div class="blog container">
                </div>
        
        <div class="contacts container">
            
        </div>
        </footer>


        <div class="cursor2"></div>
       
       <div class="cursor"></div>
    
    </main>
    <section>

        <div class="projects">
            <div class="project_content">
                <div class="graphic_content">
            
                </div>
                <div class="project_description">
                    <h1>TITLE TITLE</h1>
                    <p> text
                        </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
         
            </div>
           
    </section>




</body>
</html>
```